# no. of permutations with no increasing subsequence of three terms

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Penguin Brainteaser : 321-avoiding permutations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155867/penguin-brainteaser-321-avoiding-permutations)

In how many ways can we permute set of n numbers such that it does not have a increasing subsequence of 3 terms.

Comment: Do you mean $3$ consecutive terms, or *any* increasing subsequence of $3$ terms?

Comment: 3 increasing terms need not be consecutive

Comment: I did the first few by hand, getting $1,2,5,14$, put that into [OEIS](http://oeis.org/search?q=1%2C2%2C5%2C14&language=english&go=Search) and the first one that came up was the Catalan numbers.  It's a good bet, but I haven't found the bijection to prove it.

Comment: These are the so-called $123$-avoiding permutations. Clearly there is a bijection between them and the $321$-avoiding permutations, i.e., those that do not have a $3$-term decreasing subsequence. You’ll find two solutions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/155867/12042), one in full detail and the other clearly sketched.

Comment: @Ross: There are several bijections with more familiar Catalan families, but none of them that I’ve seen is especially obvious. We have seen this problem (or rather, its inversion) before, though.